# Use of the spread operator in function arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays

I came across a course, where the instructor used the following function arguments

```
const filteredBody = filteredObj(req.body, "name", "email");
```

Then he defined the function as the follows:

```
const filteredObj = (obj, ...allowedFields) => {
  const newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((el) => {
    if (allowedFields.includes(el)) {
      newObj[el] = obj[el];
    }
  });

  return newObj;
};
```

I am new to Javascript and I am having trouble understanding how he converted the arguments `"name","email"` into an array of `allowedFields` using `...allowedFields`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you prefixed last parameter in a function with `...` it becomes **[rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)**, which will cause all remaining parameters to be placed within a standard JavaScript array.

`allowedFields` in the below code becomes **[rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)** which allows a function to accept an indefinite number of arguments as an array.

```
const filteredObj = (obj, ...allowedFields) => {
  const newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((el) => {
    if (allowedFields.includes(el)) {
      newObj[el] = obj[el];
    }
  });

  return newObj;
};
```